# Customised mule component that creates streamed payload?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am trying to find the simplest and quickest way of creating streamed payload in a mule flow. Ideally this would be a java component.

The whole reason is I have a datamapper right next to this and mapping in stream mode. So I would prefer this payload will be a streamed pojo collection. I have tried just implement the Callable interface, but it seems difficult for me to find a proper way to output a stream payload and let Mule go on processing next step in flow while with this stream.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make your component produce a `java.io.InputStream` payload.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @TomRedfern Sorry but this is an answer, not a botched question. Rephrased, used "Make" instead of "Have" since it's apparently unclear.

Comment: Hi @DavidDossot, believe or not you have been helping us all the time around those stackoverflow questions, thanks.  In this particular case, we would want a streamed pojo collection payload into the datamapper and map from there.
The challenge I had was if the java component was just a callable one, how should I ask it return a inputStream payload and also let Mule know the payload will constantly come out so go ahead process next step(data mapping)?

Comment: Good question. I imagine DataMapper will handle the streaming payload correctly. You should be able to return an InputStream from `onCall`, since the return type is `Object`.